# Closure compiler dependencies example doesn't work

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I've been trying for days to get the examples from [this page](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies) to work but cannot get even one example compile correctly.

```
// File 1 - icecream.js
goog.provide('ice.cream');

// File 2 - cone.js
goog.provide('waffle.cone');

// File 3 - shop.js
goog.provide('ice.cream.Shop');
goog.require('ice.cream');
goog.require('waffle.cone');
```

I've added compiler.jar into the same folder and try to run the command:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js
```

But, the result is still an error:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\test>java -jar compiler.jar --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js
shop.js:3: ERROR - required "ice.cream" namespace not provided yet
goog.require('ice.cream');
^

shop.js:4: ERROR - required "waffle.cone" namespace not provided yet
goog.require('waffle.cone');
^

2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

What have I missed? Why does this example not work?

Here is my test project: https://github.com/roydukkey/moist/tree/stackoverflow-32745379

Answer (score 0):

Your compile command is missing the [dependency management flags](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies).

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js shop.js --js icecream.js
    --js cone.js --only_closure_dependencies
    --closure_entry_point="ice.cream.Shop"
```

Comment: Your files contain the UTF-8 BOM as the first character. Either remove that, or move your `goog.` statements off of the first line.

Comment: ??!!! That fixed it. I've seen this interfere with other things, but why does the BOM have an affect here?

Comment: Because the compiler uses a regular expression to search for those statements and the UTF-8 BOM interferes with that.

Comment: The compiler has now been patched to ignore UTF8 BOM characters. The change should appear in releases in October 2015 and later.